# Change the Bluetooth device volume from my iOS device

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, bluetooth

I paired my iPhone with speakers connected to my laptop running Ubuntu and I am streaming audio via Bluetooth.

It works fine, but I cannot change the volume from my iPhone. I am not sure if this is a bug or that's simply how the Bluetooth devices work (maybe each one has its own volume controls?).

But anyways, I would like to be able to control the volume from my iPhone.

Is there any chance to do that?

Otherwise, I can simply set up a local server on my Ubuntu machine and change the volume via a web interface, but I would avoid that.

Comment: "I connected my Ubuntu laptop to iPhone and I am streaming audio via Bluetooth." Can you elaborate on this? How have you connected the laptop to iPhone and how are you setting up the streaming?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Well, on my iOS devices I have the option to select the Bluetooth audio output. So, I can listen to Spotify etc. with audio in the speakers connected to the laptop. It works like any Bluetooth audio gadget. But I can’t seem to control the volume from my iOS devices.

Comment: It depends on the kind of Bluetooth speakers you have. Generally the volume control works independently for your iPhone and your Bluetooth speakers. Some Bluetooth speakers use the phone volume control to determine the speaker volume. You can verify for your your particular speaker.